# Regex to prefix URI in apache RewriteRule and execute a find/replace

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to prefix all URI in the apache vhost conf by "redirect-lang" and change the "/" to "%". For example :

```
http://example.com/category/article/how/to/redirect
```

Will become:

```
http://example.com/redirect-lang/category%article%how%to%redirect
```

To do so, I wrote the following :

```
RewriteRule (.*)([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}$1$2-$3
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?!(.*)(\/?redirect)) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/redirect/$0 [L]
```

The first `RewriteRule` Works perfectly alone in replacing the "/" with "%", but when adding the `RewriteCond` and the second `RewriteRule`, it goes in an infinite loop.

Anyone to help me with this ?

Comment: Presence of `%` will make URL invalid. Why do you want to replace `/` by `%`?

Comment: To receive it as a route's variable in PHP and process it

Comment: PHP can receive full URL with `/` as well and you can explode it on `/`

Comment: mmm... You're certainly right I'll test it. However, I still need to prefix the URI with redirect-lang (or whatever) to detect the route, and with the actual route, i'm going for an infinite loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rewrite each URL with prefix `/redirect-lang/` use this rule as **very first rule**:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!redirect-lang/).*)$ redirect-lang/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Got a 500 internal error. Even when escaping the "/" :(

Comment: [core:error] [pid 6348:tid 1020] [client 127.0.0.1:50326] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: And I assure you that this is the only redirection I have !!

Comment: Neither. And when adding the `http://%{HTTP_HOST}` I got something like infinite loop

Comment: i'll try later after getting some rest. (I'm beggining with regex and just spent 12 hours on this one). Thanks for your efforts ! I'll keep you up to date

Comment: I deleted all the other rule and kept the one you listed and I get an error 400 :


Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand

Comment: As I said earlier also same code works on my Apache so it must be something locally in your environment.

Comment: which version of apache do you have ? I am on a 2.4

Comment: I am also using Apache 2.4

Comment: When creating a directory named "redirect-lang" in the root of my site and an "index.html" file, the rewrite rule runs well. The rewriterule doesn't alter the "Path" but the "target folder"

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `rewriterule doesn't alter the "Path" but the "target folder"`. Please clarify with examples.

Comment: on the `www/` directory i created a new directory named `redirect-lang` and inside this directory, i created a file named `index.html`. After rebooting Apache, I visited the site (example.com) and got redirected to the `index.html`that was inside the `redirect-lang` folder.

Comment: In other words, it is alter the DocumentRoot and not the relative path

Comment: Everything must be inside `DocumentRoot` i.e. `/www/` on your website. Above rule must be placed in `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` and `redirect-lang` should be a sub-directory right inside `DocumentRoot`